# How to check if any number of points are coplanar?

Tags: geometry, 3d

How to check if any number of tridimensional points are coplanar?

I have found just how to check if 4 points are coplanar, but I need to know if a few tenths of points are coplanar.

Comment: Consider the difference vectors $v_j - v_i$. They should all span a two-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would first do a [linear least squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares) to fit the *best approximation plane*. I use italic writing as best is a subjective matter. And then test if all the distances of the points to that plane are less than a given tolerance.

The advantage of doing so is that all points are Havin the same role.